# how to populate a vector of type "User" that has 2 components to it "username" and "password"

Tags: c++, vector, populate

So I have managed how to open up a file and read in different inputs in this file. The question is how do I grab these individual inputs (multiple iterations of username, and password) and populate a vector of type `User` that holds 2 things: username and password? 
The class for this is held in another file named `User.h` containing

```
class User
{
private:
    string username;
    string password;
public:
// etc etc etc...
};
```

Using the User class:

```
void BBoard::setup(const string & input_file)
{
    //ifstream filename;
    ////find a way to turn a string into a char pointer
    //filename.open(input_file);

    string username;
    string password;
    fstream f;

    f.open("test");
    while(f>>username)
    {
        f>>password;
        cout << username << " " << password << endl;
        //make User object and push to user_list
        user_list.at(i).username
        if(f.eof()) break;
    }
    f.close();
}
```

test file contents:

```
user1 password1
user2 password2
user3 password3
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your list contains values (and not pointers):

```
vector<User> user_list;
user_list.push_back(User(username, password));
```

If you know how many elements there are, and `User` has a default constructor, you can call `user_list.reserve(n)` for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```
//make User object and push to user_list
User user;
user.username = username;
user.password = password;
user_list.push_back(user);
```